# How to scale images to the size of an existing div while you change them dynamically with onClick?

Tags: css, image, onclick, scale

What I am trying to do is the following.

1. I have a list of hidden images.
2. I have a button activated with Jquery onclick that replaces the html of a div to  include the images
3. The button functions as a cycle button and gets a big list of images.

My problem is that the images do not scale to the size of the parent div. Even if I give them a .horizontal and .vertical class 
Any ideas?

I want to keep the format of the hidden list of images inside a div because i do some other things with the lists. I originally thought that by having two classes for the images it will work and now that I am finishing I realised that the whole idea has a problem !

http://jsfiddle.net/alexnode/ttQHt/

```
HTML
    <div id="artdiv2">
        <div id="artslide1nextbutton">></div>
        <div id="artslide1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
    <div id="1slide1">
        <img class="horizontal" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7366/9160515864_7dc851a598.jpg"  alt="Rezando a los antiguos Dioses - Praying to the old Gods">
    </div>
    <div id="1slide2">
        <img class="vertical" src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5519/9158661396_4828a06655.jpg"  alt="Drain">
    </div>
        </div>

Jquery
//i get everything called 1slide like that. 
var artslides = $('[id^=1slide]');
idxs1 = 1;
//this is my button that cycles through the image 
$("#artslide1nextbutton").on(
    "click", function () {
    $("#artslide1").html(artslides.eq(idxs1).html());
    idxs1 = idxs1 == 1? 0 : idxs1 + 1;
});

CSS
.hidden{display:none;}
#artdiv2{ position:absolute;  top:8%; left: 20%; height:70%; width:100%; background:DimGray;}
#artslide1nextbutton{position:fixed;  top:0px; left: 0px; height:auto; width:10%; background:DarkRed;pointer:cursor;}
.horizontal {position:relative; width:100%; height:auto;}
.vertical {position:relative; height:100%; width:auto;}
```

Comment: I also forgot to add that if I use pixels and no percentages in the image class the images become smaller. Ideally I would like to use percentages and css or pixels from width/height from a script.  And thank you Bodgan for the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT : answer updated to fit closer to question.:*

you could play width min and max value  and center img  with text-align:center.

demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/ttQHt/2/

```
    #artslide1 {
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        height:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
#artslide1 img {
    min-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;

}
```

Some other option to play with image

here is an idea of what happens if you can set line-height. http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/BdtEj and adding min-width/min-height http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kfIbp

Comment: The whole point was to create two classes one that fits the height and one that fits the width with %.

Comment: no need to put these appart . if you set width , height change to keep ratio of image and vice-versa. Why make it difficult and go back in force in 2 classes ? (that was my point actually ;) )

Comment: This css method with the line height is as a bit of a hack,Apart from that I cannot clip the images at all, the portrait ones have to fit in 100% height of the container div and the landscape have to fit 100% width.

Comment: turn it the other way round then :) use max-height and max-width. so landscape or portraits will fit in the right ratio and portrait will be centered. (i guess you did not really get how it worked  :) major point was to reduce virtually to zero width the image, so it centers no matter what width  :) )

Comment: line-height is not a hack, it is a natural way to center on baseline texte & inline-boxe elements :).

Answer (score 1):

Use the JQuery variable `.height()` and `.width()`

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying to do now let's see how it goes. I have to get the width of the container and then the width of the child image and then decide about the aspect ratio and then set the scale each time i load a new one. I hoped that css had a solution for that.

Comment: same issue  through CSS, be flexible :) min-width/height is like if img.width < container.width ....

Comment: Remember though you need to add an ajax file for the JQuery to work

Comment: @GCyrillus But css clips the images?

Comment: It stretches the image if that is what you mean?

Comment: yes it has to clip image either on width or height . It preserve ratio and center it .If you don't mind to strech them, jsut  set height:100% &  width:100% :) .

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mobile, so I can't try this myself, but what about putting a width and height attribute directly on the image elements, and using the button to just change the image source? That would make every image have the same width and height.

Comment: The whole design scales with percentages so it needs to get the images with percentages or ... program to set image scale and convert it to pixels. ( which is what is what I am trying now)  Apart from that there are A LOT of images.